# Ambiguous behaviour of printf() with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, stream

I am a newbie to buffered streams.I was write a simple c program which takes a string as a user  input and displays it back.My working environment is eclipse under windows.The code is as follow:

```
#include<stdio.h>

enum { max_string = 127 };

static char string[max_string+1] = ""; 

void main(){
    printf("type the input string---> \n");
    fgets(string,max_string,stdin);
    printf("the input string was ---> %s\n",string);
    }
```

While running it,the user input is taken first and the two `printf()'s` are executed after.
The output sample is:

```
user input
type the input string---> 
the input string was ---> user input
```

I tried the upper code in CodeBlocks IDE and it worked fine.The output is as follow:

```
type the input string--->
user input
the input string was ---> user input
```

What is the problem?
I also added a `\n` at the last of my `printf()` so as to flush them immediately.

Regards.

Comment: This seems to be an eclipse/windows issue. The first output block is definitely not what you would expect from a well behaving run time environment.

Comment: @RSahu, then what should i do to make it work.

Comment: try doing `fflush(stdout); ` after `printf`

Comment: @Prakash,thanks.I want to know , if there is any permanent solution to do this. I mean, is there any way to disable this ***extra*** buffering.

Comment: Using which version of Eclipse you are observing this behaviour. Also which operating system is it running on. I cannot reproduce this on Eclipse Juno SR1 on Debian Stable.

Comment: @alk, Eclipse Kepler SR2 on windows7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdout` is line-buffered only if connected to a terminal. Eclipse's terminal-emulation might not be detected as terminal.

From [`man stdout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdin.3.html):

> The stream stdout is line-buffered when it points to a terminal.

There are several way to get around this limitation:

- call `fflush(stdout)` every time output shall appear
- set `stdout` to be unbuffered by using [`setvbuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) like this

  ```
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  ```

  prior to using `stdout`.
- use `stderr` which isn't buffered by default

Answer (score 0):

OK!! after some googling i found out that the eclipse terminal emulator do more buffering than the normal terminal.We need to do `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` to make it working.