# Functions in my program seem to not be waiting for other functions to finish

Tags: c

I am new to coding, and this is my first big assignment.
I have to design a program that receives inputs from stdin and outputs specific data when asked (throught "report" command)

```c
int main()
{
  const char Comando[6][7]={"addrel","addent","delrel","delent","report","end"};
  const char spazio[2]= " ";
  const char newline[3] = "\n";
  const char quote[2]= "\"";
  char sample[100];
  char *temp;
  char *comandoIN;
  char *argomento1;
  char *dest;
  char *rel;


  RelHead = NULL;
  init_array();

  char *str = fgets(sample, 100, stdin);
/*I am not going to use str, but apparently I have to do this , otherwise it won't compile*/

    for(;;)
    {
      if (strncmp (sample, Comando[5], 3)==0)
      {
        return 0; //check if input is end, if so terminate
      }
      else
      {
        //parse by eliminating \n character and quotes containing arguments
        temp = strtok(sample, newline);
        comandoIN = strtok(temp, spazio);
        argomento1 = strtok(NULL, quote);
        temp = strtok(NULL, quote);
        dest = strtok(NULL, quote);
        temp = strtok(NULL, quote);
        rel = strtok(NULL, quote);

        if (strncmp(Comando[0], comandoIN, 7)==0)
          {
            addrel(argomento1, dest, rel);
          }
        else if (strncmp(Comando[1], comandoIN, 7)==0)
          {
            addent(argomento1);
          }
        else if (strncmp(Comando[2], comandoIN, 7)==0)
          {
            delrel(argomento1, dest, rel);
          }
        else if (strncmp(Comando[3], comandoIN, 7)==0)
          {
            delent(argomento1);
          }
        else if (strncmp(Comando[4], comandoIN, 7)==0)
          {
            report();
          }
        }

      char *str = fgets(sample, 69, stdin);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

When I try test the program with some standadized inputs given by the professor, the program seems to not output right after "report" is called, it instead keeps reading and outputs later.

For example, this input:

```
addent "Elijah_Baley"
addent "Bentley_Baley"
addent "Jesse_Baley"
addent "Gladia_Delmarre"
addent "Han_Fastolfe"
addent "Vasilia_Aliena"
addent "R_Daneel_Olivaw"
addent "R_Giskard_Reventlov"
addent "Kelden_Amadiro"
addent "Santirix_Gremionis"
addent "Rikaine_Delmarre"
report
addent "Jothan_Leebig"
addent "The_Chairman"
addent "R_Jander_Panell"
addent "Hannis_Gruer"
addrel "Elijah_Baley" "Jesse_Baley" "loves"
report
addrel "Gladia_Delmarre" "Elijah_Baley" "loves"
addrel "Rikaine_Delmarre" "Jothan_Leebig" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Jesse_Baley" "Elijah_Baley" "loves"
report
addrel "R_Jander_Panell" "R_Giskard_Reventlov" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Santirix_Gremionis" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "Gladia_Delmarre" "R_Jander_Panell" "loves"
addrel "Elijah_Baley" "Kelden_Amadiro" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Gladia_Delmarre" "Elijah_Baley" "is_killed_by"
report
addrel "Elijah_Baley" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "R_Jander_Panell" "Kelden_Amadiro" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Vasilia_Aliena" "Han_Fastolfe" "loves"
report
addrel "Jesse_Baley" "Jothan_Leebig" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Bentley_Baley" "Elijah_Baley" "loves"
report
addrel "Rikaine_Delmarre" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "R_Jander_Panell" "Kelden_Amadiro" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Santirix_Gremionis" "Vasilia_Aliena" "loves"
addrel "Vasilia_Aliena" "Kelden_Amadiro" "loves"
addrel "Kelden_Amadiro" "R_Daneel_Olivaw" "loves"
report
addrel "Santirix_Gremionis" "Elijah_Baley" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Han_Fastolfe" "Vasilia_Aliena" "loves"
report
addrel "The_Chairman" "Jothan_Leebig" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Hannis_Gruer" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "R_Daneel_Olivaw" "Vasilia_Aliena" "is_killed_by"
addrel "The_Chairman" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "R_Giskard_Reventlov" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "Vasilia_Aliena" "R_Giskard_Reventlov" "loves"
report
addrel "Vasilia_Aliena" "Jesse_Baley" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Kelden_Amadiro" "Han_Fastolfe" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Santirix_Gremionis" "R_Daneel_Olivaw" "loves"
report
addrel "The_Chairman" "Kelden_Amadiro" "is_killed_by"
report
end
```

outputs this:

```
addent "Elijah_Baley"
addent "Bentley_Baley"
addent "Jesse_Baley"
addent "Gladia_Delmarre"
addent "Han_Fastolfe"
addent "Vasilia_Aliena"
addent "R_Daneel_Olivaw"
addent "R_Giskard_Reventlov"
addent "Kelden_Amadiro"
addent "Santirix_Gremionis"
addent "Rikaine_Delmarre"
report
addent "Jothan_Leebig"
addent "The_Chairman"
addent "R_Jander_Panell"
addent "Hannis_Gruer"
addrel "Elijah_Baley" "Jesse_Baley" "loves"
report
addrel "Gladia_Delmarre" "Elijah_Baley" "loves"
addrel "Rikaine_Delmarre" "Jothan_Leebig" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Jesse_Baley" "Elijah_Baley" "loves"
report
addrel "R_Jander_Panell" "R_Giskard_Reventlov" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Santirix_Gremionis" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "Gladia_Delmarre" "R_Jander_Panell" "loves"
addrel "Elijah_Baley" "Kelden_Amadiro" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Gladia_Delmarre" "Elijah_Baley" "is_killed_by"
report
addrel "Elijah_Baley" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "R_Jander_Panell" "Kelden_Amadiro" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Vasilia_Aliena" "Han_Fastolfe" "loves"
report
addrel "Jesse_Baley" "Jothan_Leebig" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Bentley_Baley" "Elijah_Baley" "loves"
report
addrel "Rikaine_Delmarre" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "R_Jander_Panell" "Kelden_Amadiro" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Santirix_Gremionis" "Vasilia_Aliena" "loves"
addrel "Vasilia_Aliena" "Kelden_Amadiro" "loves"
addrel "Kelden_Amadiro" "R_Daneel_Olivaw" "loves"
report
addrel "Santirix_Gremionis" "Elijah_Baley" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Han_Fastolfe" "Vasilia_Aliena" "loves"
report
addrel "The_Chairman" "Jothan_Leebig" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Hannis_Gruer" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "R_Daneel_Olivaw" "Vasilia_Aliena" "is_killed_by"
addrel "The_Chairman" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "R_Giskard_Reventlov" "Gladia_Delmarre" "loves"
addrel "Vasilia_Aliena" "R_Giskard_Reventlov" "loves"
report
addrel "Vasilia_Aliena" "Jesse_Baley" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Kelden_Amadiro" "Han_Fastolfe" "is_killed_by"
addrel "Santirix_Gremionis" "R_Daneel_Olivaw" "loves"
report
addrel "The_Chairman" "Kelden_Amadiro" "is_killed_by"
renone //Starts outputting here, between "re" and "port", 9 lines below
"loves" "Jesse_Baley" 1;
"is_killed_by" "Jothan_Leebig" 1; "loves" "Elijah_Baley" 2;
"is_killed_by" "Jothan_Leebig" 1; "loves" "Elijah_Baley" 2;
"is_killed_by" "Kelden_Amadiro" 2; "loves" "Elijah_Baley" 2;
"is_killed_by" "Kelden_Amadiro" "Jothan_Leebig" 2; "loves" "Elijah_Baley" 3;
"is_killed_by" "Kelden_Amadiro" "Jothan_Leebig" 2; "loves" "Elijah_Baley" 3;
"is_killed_by" "Kelden_Amadiro" "Jothan_Leebig" 2; "loves" "Elijah_Baley" 3;
"is_killed_by" "Jothan_Leebig" 3; "loves" "Gladia_Delmarre" 6;
"is_killed_by" "Jothan_Leebig" 3; "loves" "Gladia_Delmarre" 6;
port
end
"is_killed_by" "Jothan_Leebig" 3; "loves" "Gladia_Delmarre" 6;
```

So my understanding is that it outputs after it's done reading, which is not intended behaviour

Comment: At a glance, your "output" appears to be identical to your "input".  Is this a copy-paste mistake, or is this actually what the program is outputting?  It might be helpful to create a smaller example, show what is actually output and also show your expected output.  It probably also would be necessary to show the body of `report()` and at least one other function such as `addent()`.

Comment: @DaveCosta it seems that the output goes wrong near the bottom, where an additional chunk of text is inserted. `//Starts outputting here, between "re" and "port", 9 lines below`

Comment: You haven't shown any code that generates output. Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Aside: the idiomatic loop control is `while(fgets(sample, sizeof sample, stdin) != NULL) { ... }` and remove the `for(;;)`

Comment: There is no _"output right after "report" is called"_.  Presumably `report()` does the outputting?  You have not provided the code that generated that output.  Are you using Eclipse by any chance?  If so I am betting on this problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877966/ambiguous-behaviour-of-printf-with-eclipse

Comment: I am not using eclipse, I will update with additional code when I get home, but I think @WeatherVane has found the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the input text is

```
report
```

you continue to call `strtok` when it has already returned `NULL`.

This causes undefined behaviour, because there is no telling what will happen when `strtok` continues to parse outside the range of your input, especially as it **writes a nul-terminator** to memory somewhere beyond your string.

So you are causing memory corruption by this practice. The solution is to stop calling `strtok` when it returns `NULL`, because there are *no more tokens to extract*.

Comment: That's it, thank you again! You are everywhere in this site