# strtok returns NULL despite not having reached the end of the string

Tags: c

I am writing a program that parses input from stdin and calls functions according to the input.
The inputs my program is supposed to handle are the following:

```
end //stops the program
report //prints a specific output
addent "ent_id"
delent "ent_id"
addrel "ent_id1" "ent_id2" "rel_id"
delrel "ent_id1" "ent_id2" "rel_id"
```

The functions called by the input are not relevant to my issue, but do note the all the arguments that are passed to the functions are between quotation marks.

Here's the code

```
int main() {
    const char Comando[6][7] = { "addrel", "addent", "delrel", "delent", "report", "end" };
    const char spazio[2] = " ";
    const char newline[3] = "\n";
    const char quote[2] = "\"";
    char sample[100];
    char *temp;
    char *comandoIN;
    char *argomento1;
    char *dest;
    char *rel;

    RelHead = NULL;
    init_array();

    char *str = fgets(sample, 100, stdin);

    for (;;) {
        if (strncmp(sample, Comando[5], 3) == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (strncmp(sample, Comando[4], 6) == 0) {
            report();
        } else {
            temp = strtok(sample, newline);
            comandoIN = strtok(temp, spazio);
            argomento1 = strtok(NULL, quote);

            if (strncmp(Comando[1], comandoIN, 7) == 0) {
                addent(argomento1);
            } else if (strncmp(Comando[3], comandoIN, 7) == 0) {
                delent(argomento1);
            } else {
                temp = strtok(NULL, quote);
                dest = strtok(NULL, quote);
                temp = strtok(NULL, quote);
                rel = strtok(NULL, quote);

                if (strncmp(Comando[0], comandoIN, 7) == 0) {
                    addrel(argomento1, dest, rel);
                } else if (strncmp(Comando[2], comandoIN, 7) == 0) {
                    delrel(argomento1, dest, rel);
                }
            }
        }

        char *str = fgets(sample, 69, stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The incorrect behavior is cause by the following input:

```
addrel "The_Ruler_of_the_Universe" "The_Lajestic_Vantrashell_of_Lob" "knows"
```

which causes the last two calls of `strtok` to return `NULL` instead of `" "` (whitespace) and `"knows"` respectively (without quotation marks).
Furthermore, if this is the first input given to the program, it behaves correctly, and if it's the last, the following cycle will put `"knows"` in the `"comandoIN"` variable. This is the only input I've found so far that causes this issue, and I think it has something to do with removing the newline character with the first call of `strtok`.

This is an assignment for uni, so we have several inputs to test the program, and my program passes the first 4 of these (the tests are about 200 inputs each), so I don't really understand what's causing the bug. Any ideas?

Comment: you can't switch between multiple strings passed to strtok, store all the results of the first string in an array or someting

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger to see what it does?

Comment: @Hogan the first one just removed the newline. Then starts again.

Comment: @WeatherVane -- he does strtok on `sample`, then strtok on `temp` and then switches back to `sample` and is asking why it does not work.  strtok stores state internally not on the variable it is working on.

Comment: @Hogan all the other `strtok` calls are passing `NULL` not `sample.` The second call is starting over with a truncated string, not mixing two searches. Note this is allied to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412551/functions-in-my-program-seem-to-not-be-waiting-for-other-functions-to-finish) where the same technique was employed, but that wasn't the problem. But I agree, it is better to put the `\n` as one of the delimiters.

Comment: @Jack do you know you can put multiple delimiters in the string passed to `strtok`? Also, you keep calling `strtok` without checking if the last call returned `NULL` and this was the problem with the previous question.

Comment: Are you really using `strtok()` to remove newline characters? Because `fgets()` won't span a newline, even reading from a file. `sample[ strcspn( sample, "\n" ) ] = '\0';` is a much simpler way to remove newline characters at the end of a string.

Comment: @WeatherVane This is the first time I ever use strtok, so I don't know the ins and outs of the functions yet. I am not sure I understand your question: am I supposed to check if it returns `NULL`? and if so, why should I? I don't have to check if the input follows the accepted format, so if the command is not end, report, addrel or addent, it should have 3 strings enclosed by quotation marks. I don't understand why the input cited about causes this error

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am somewhat new to programming, so I don't know all the library functions yet. strtok seemed to get the job done, but again, I don't think that's relevant to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the input:

```
addrel "The_Ruler_of_the_Universe" "The_Lajestic_Vantrashell_of_Lob" "knows"
```

is 77 bytes long (76 characters plus terminating NULL).

At the end of your loop you have:

```
char *str = fgets(sample, 69, stdin);
```

where your state that your buffer is 69 long.

Why does it behave correctly if it is the first input?

Before the for loop you have:

```
char *str = fgets(sample, 100, stdin);
for(;;)
...
```

Here you use a size of 100, so it works if you first use the above input directly after starting the program.

Comment: Yes! That's it, thank you so much! Lesson learnt: being childish and programming don't go well together

Comment: The main loop should be `while (fgets(sample, sizeof sample, stdin))` instead of making 2 separate calls to `fgets()` with hard coded sizes and ignoring the return value (`NULL` indicates the end of file)

Answer (score 1):

Using `strtok` for parsing the command line with different sets of separators is confusing and error prone. It would be simpler to parse the command line with a simple loop and handle spaces and quotes explicitly, then dispatch on the first word.

Here is a more systematic approach:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *getarg(char **pp) {
    char *p = *pp;
    char *arg = NULL;
    while (*p == ' ')
         p++;
    if (*p == '\0' || *p == '\n')
        return arg;
    if (*p == '"') {
        arg = ++p;
        while (*p != '\0' && *p != '"')
            p++;
        if (*p == '"')
            *p++ = '\0';
    } else {
        arg = p++;
        while (*p != '\0' && *p != ' ' && *p != '\n')
            p++;
        if (*p != '\0')
            *p++ = '\0';
    }
    *pp = p;
    return arg;
}

int main() {
    char sample[100];
    char *cmd, *arg1, *arg2, *arg3;

    RelHead = NULL;
    init_array();

    while (fgets(sample, sizeof sample, stdin)) {
        char *p = sample;
        cmd = getarg(&p);
        arg1 = getarg(&p);
        arg2 = getarg(&p);
        arg3 = getarg(&p);

        if (cmd == NULL) {  // empty line
            continue;
        } else
        if (!strcmp(cmd, "end")) {
            break;
        } else
        if (!strcmp(cmd, "report")) {
            report();
        } else
        if (!strcmp(cmd, "addent")) {
            addent(arg1);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(cmd, "delent")) {
            delent(arg1);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(cmd, "addrel")) {
            addrel(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(cmd, "delrel")) {
            delrel(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        } else {
            printf("invalid command\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```